# In ASP.net if server side code files (vb.net or c# ) removed. How can build or compile the project

Tags: asp.net

In my current asp.net project someone removed server side file (.vb). when I am trying to build I am getting errors. How can build or compile my project without server side file any way please tell me.

Comment: Not possible to answer this due to lack of details... The deleted server side files are probably referenced by other code?

Comment: Is this an "ASP.NET Website" or an "ASP.NET Web Application"? They have different means of being built - Websites require the `.vb` files to run, whereas web applications do not because they're pre-built separately (and have a `bin` directory with `dll` files).

Comment: Well, both will at some point require the code to compile

Comment: If the vb files really are irrecoverable, but you do have a recent copy of the DLL files for the project, you may be able to use a decompiler to regain some version of the .vb files.

Answer (score 0):

If your project uses "code-behind" model (most do) your ASPX files contain only page markup (controls layout, their properties etc.) Actual code is located in separate VB files and unfortunately without them there is no way your project will compile.

You will either have to find a way to restore them somehow (backup? source control?) or rebuild them from scratch